# Multiple strings for one Variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a system which allows for authorizing a transaction via a Admin ID. I wish to have multiple Admin ID's, to track which user made the transaction.

```
$txtKnownAdminHash = "c0b71d437b9138ce3c1860b09b8923ebed6f8aeb3db4093458f38300f6f24eaa";     

$txtHashedAdminID = hash('sha256', $txtAdminID);
  if ($txtKnownAdminHash != $txtHashedAdminID) {
```

I want to allow for $txtKnownAdminHash to have multiple values, which is then checked.

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the Admin IDs in an array.

```
$txtKnownAdminHash = array("hash1", "hash2", "hash3", "hash4");
```

To check if the `$txtHashedAdminID` is in the array, you can use `in_array()`.
This will check if `$txtHashedAdminID` is in `$txtKnownAdminHash` array:

```
<?php

    if (in_array($txtHashedAdminID, $txtKnownAdminHash)) {
        // the hash is in the array
    } else {
        // the hash is not in the array
    }

?>
```

Read more about:

- PHP `array()`: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp.
- PHP `in_array()`: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp.